# Excel match and re-arrange

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would appreciate your help with a specific task I was not able to accomplish.

In columns A and B I have specific ID information. Each ID in column A is connected to and corresponds to the ID in column B. In column C I have the same set of IDs (presumably) contained in column B, but mixed up in different order. In this case, each ID in column C is connected to and corresponds to the information on the same row (columns D and E). First, I would need to match the IDs in column B with the IDs in column C (assuming potential discrepancies). Second, I need to re-arrange the ID on each row in column B to connect to the corresponding ID from column C (both matching IDs to be on the same row). However, I would still need to have Column A and Column B IDs connected to each other, as my end goal is to connect the info from D and E to Column A sus. ID. Could you please help me sort this out, with the current information available?

[image]

Comment: What's the base list you want to work with (assuming there might be discrepancies) is it A and B and add to it the matching info from D and E, or is it C and add to it the matching info from A?

Answer (score 0):

This feels like two separate sets of (related) data, but by keeping them next to each other you will make lots of things harder to do as Excel will assume it is one data range.

I suggest inserting two columns between B and C, so C becomes E and you have room for a new formula and a blank column to separate things out.
In the new empty column C, add this formula and copy down:

```
=MATCH($B2,$C$2:$C$9999,0) (or however long column C is)
```

Sort columns A:C based on column C and the data will line up B and E. This assumes every value in B is also in E, and vice versa. If that is not the case you will need something slightly cleverer.
You could insert a column to the left instead of in between, and put this formula in the new column A, but just be careful when you sort the data to only re-shuffle A through C.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this can be looked at as a sorting problem:

- Break into two table (the first two and the last three columns)
- Sort the first table so that column B is in the same order as Column C

  - That order will be returned by the `XMATCH` function
- recombine the two tables

Assuming no version constraints as per your tags, and also assuming your data is in a `Table` named `Table_1` so we can use structured references, you can do this with a single formula, and the results will `SPILL` to the output range

```
=VSTACK(Table_1[#Headers],
                HSTACK(
                      SORTBY(CHOOSECOLS(Table_1,1,2), XMATCH(Table_1[ac. ID],Table_1[ac. ID v2])),
                      CHOOSECOLS(Table_1,3,4,5)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!